# Refresh in C3.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, c3.js

I'm trying to use $interval function in C3.js to refresh bar chart with new value

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.chart.load({
      columns: ["England", 5]
    });
  }, 1000);
```

but the value isn't displayed after interval function execution. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRYHAJiMu0hjwQrksjLv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

columns is an array of arrays - so double square brackets

```
      columns: [["England", 5]]
```